# How to call setState in a extended class?

Tags: flutter

```
class Cari  extends AnaState implements InterHttp {
  String token = Tokenlar.token();

   Future<Void>  getCariHareket() async {
    final response = await get(
      "http://148.111.156.214:36555/Api/Customers/CustomerActionById/3",
      headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "bearer $token",HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: "application/json"},      
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) 
    {
      List<CariHareketListe> hareketListe=(json.decode(response.body) as List).map((i) =>
              CariHareketListe.fromJson(i)).toList();  
      //Map<String,dynamic> map =  json.decode(response.body); 
      setState(() {
        provider = hareketListe;
      });
    } 
    else 
    {
      throw Exception('Cari hareket listesi yükleme başarısız oldu');
    }
  }

}
```

i want to be able to call setstate in this class but it gives me this error:

FlutterError (setState() called in constructor: Cari#ed627(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)
This happens when you call setState() on a State object for a widget that hasn't been inserted into the widget tree yet. It is not necessary to call setState() in the constructor, since the state is already assumed to be dirty when it is initially created.)

This is the main dart i want to setstate in cari then i want that data go into Icwidgetlar to be able to Return a list view to Anastate

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:guven_avize/ApiMetodlar/CariMetod.dart';
import 'Veriler/CariVeriler.dart';
class Anamenu 
{
  Anamenu() 
  {

  }
}
class Ana extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  AnaState createState() => AnaState();
}



class IcWidgetlar  
{
    List<CariHareketListe> provider = new List<CariHareketListe>();

ListView icyapi(int secilenTab)
{

  if (secilenTab == 0) 
  {    
    Cari cari = new Cari();
    cari.veriCek(1);
ListView.builder(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  itemCount: provider.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${provider[index]}')),
    );
  }
);
  }
}
}




class AnaState extends State<Ana> with IcWidgetlar {

IcWidgetlar widgetlar = new IcWidgetlar();

int selectedIndex = 0;
 static const TextStyle optionStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
 static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
  Text(
    'Cari',
    style: optionStyle,
  ),
  Text(
     'Stok',
     style: optionStyle,
  ),
  Text(
     'Sipariş',
     style: optionStyle,
  ),
];

void _onItemTapped(int index) {
  setState(() {
    selectedIndex = index;
  });
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async => false,     
child: Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
     automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
     backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(106, 112, 222, 50),
      title: _widgetOptions.elementAt(selectedIndex),
    ),  
    body: widgetlar.icyapi(selectedIndex),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(      
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.face),
          title: Text('Cari'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.inbox),
          title: Text('Stok'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
          title: Text('Sipariş'),
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    ),
  ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you not returning the result instead?

Instead of returning Future, return Future>, and get it from other class.

You can even use FutureBuilder to wait until the response arrive.

Call the function in initState

```
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        getCariHareket().then( (list) {
                      setState((){
                          provider = list;
                      }())
        });
    }
```

Comment: that gives this error  "future<dynamic> is not a subtype of List<cariHareketListe>"

Comment: You should use .then after calling that function. I will edit my answer in a few seconds to show the example

Comment: Check out this video, to learn more about [FutureBuilder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo)

Comment: pardon me i am new to flutter where should i put that method in ?

Comment: Inside of a state. In your case, inside of `class AnaState extends State<Ana> with IcWidgetlar`

Comment: i resolved that issue. your answer did not fix my error but thank you for helping me kardeşim :)

Comment: Problem değil, hall ettiğine sevindim.